# Is there a way to set and update the background image in blender 2.8 2d animation workspace?

Tags: blender

As the title suggests, Is there a way to set and update the background image in blender 2.8 2d animation workspace? I mean it's easy enough to add a background by dragging the image onto the viewport but then I can't seem to interact with it at all or change it to a different image.

Just to point out it's fairly easy to change background in a 3d project. What I'm asking for is updating the background image in a 2d project. I want this for a reference image.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2.80 no longer has "background images" like previous versions.

The *Add->Image->Reference* actually adds an [empty](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/modeling/empties.html) that is set to display as an image. You can set the empties properties to adjust the display options which includes the image displayed, you can also move it around like any other object.

There is also now a [background image settings for camera objects](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/render/cameras.html#background-images), this looks like the old background image settings, but is part of the camera settings and is only visible in camera view.